# need to show croatian, spanish symbols in my device in android

Tags: android

I need to get a json file from an URL, parse it and get the contents. This Json contains Croatian characters and symbols like this "Pošaljite e-marlon". I used the following code to get the Json file from the URL. This is the URL I used http://ptracker.com/webteh/localization.php

```
InputStream is = null;
                try {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(language_url);

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String json = null;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-2")), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                    Log.v("json >>", json);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error",
                            "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
```

The response json doesn't show the original String "Pošaljite e-marlon". It gives "Poaljite e-mailom". How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is your are assuming your response is encoded using ISO-8859-2. Try to check the response headers to see if you can obtain the encoding description, something like:

```
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

UPDATE: I used a trick to get the charset: I opened Firebug and I ran in the console `document.characterSet` which returned `"windows-1252"`. Then I did this little example and it worked. I'm not sure this charset is supported in Android, but...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url= new URL("http://ptracker.com/webteh/localization.php");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        System.out.println(con.getContentType());
        BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
                  con.getInputStream(),Charset.forName("windows-1252")));
        String s=null;
        while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using UTF-8, the result is like this "Po�aljite e-mailom"

Comment: The default encoding of my Firefox to show that page is UTF-8 and I can see all characteres... I'll check it deeper later

Comment: Pablo, did you check the URL?

Comment: I did it, here you have :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  the Charset UTF-8, because [ISO_8859-2](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-2) does not support spanish symbols.

Comment: Using UTF-8, the result is like this "Po�aljite e-mailom"

Comment: The Charset you used serverside is ISO_8859-1. Now you have two options. You either change the used Charset in Java-Code also to ISO_8859-1, or you use on both sides UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Biagio is right, you need UTF-8. I tried your code (using croatian characters) and it works OK with this modification:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")), 8);
```

Comment: Using UTF-8, the result is like this "Po�aljite e-mailom"

Comment: did you try toString("ISO-8859-1") ?